# Populating parameter list with a query

Tags: looker-studio

I have a custom big query that functions correctly, but I would like to add a parameter to that query. I would have expected to be able to populate the drop down list with another query but cannot see how to do it. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot populate a BigQuery query parameter dropdown list using another BigQuery query.

A workaround for this would be:

1. create a [Community Connector](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/connector/get-started) using [Advanced Services](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/connector/advanced-services)
2. Add the query parameter as a [config param](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/connector/reference#getconfig)
3. in `getConfig`, use BigQuery REST API or Apps Script BigQuery service to retrieve list
4. in `getData`, pass the parameter from your `getConfig` to BigQuery